# How to restrict JTextField not taking more than 'x' numbers of inputs

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a JTextField. That takes in strings. For one JTextField, I want to limit to only two strings. For example 'fa' or '56' or '..'  Not more than two.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [Formatted Text Field](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).

Or you can create a custom [Document Filter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter).

Creating a custom Document is an old approach that is generally not used anymore.